# How to check if Username/Email already exists android parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

I've searched everywhere but haven't found anything about how to check if a username/email address in the parse database is taken. I've found some answers on the internet on parse.com forums but they weren't clear. 
Thanks if you could help. 
**If this has an answer somewhere, then please comment instead of marking so I can delete it.**

Comment: If you are talking about signup functionality, the parse api does this automatically for you when you try to sign up. If the username exists, parse will handle this.

Comment: @Handsomeguy Yes. That's true, however the errors could vary and I want to give it a specific error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will do what you need if I understand your question correctly:

```
final ParseQuery<ParseUser> emailQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();
            emailQuery.whereEqualTo("email", emailAddress);
            final ParseQuery<ParseUser> usernameQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();
            usernameQuery.whereEqualTo("email", username);
            List<ParseQuery> queries = new ArrayList<>();
            queries.add(emailQuery);
            queries.add(usernameQuery);
            final ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseQuery.or(queries);
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
                public void done(List<ParseUser> results, ParseException e) {
                    // results has the list of users that match either the email address or username
                }
            });
```

https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#queries-compound-queries

Or you could do it this way:

```
user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    // yippee!!
                } else {

                    switch (e.getCode()) {
                        case ParseException.USERNAME_TAKEN: {
                            // report error
                            break;
                        }
                        case ParseException.EMAIL_TAKEN: {
                            // report error
                            break;
                        }
                        default: {
                            // Something else went wrong
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to check your data in parse. I hope this will helpful for you.

```
// this is create query of your parse table
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<>(your prars tableName);
    query.whereEqualTo(YourParseColumeNameEmail, yourEmail);
    query.whereEqualTo(YourParseColumeNamePassword, yourPassword);

    // this is for doing in background
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                if (scoreList.size() == 0) {
                   // if there is no data like your email and password then it,s come here
                } else {
                    // if there is data like your email and password then it,s come here
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```